# How to check a table row is empty in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check whether a row is empty or not in PHP. If "$jfeta3" is not empty, it gives the value of "Success", otherwise it goes to the else part. Inside the else part, if "$jfeta['rate_number']" is greater than 0, it gives the value of "Success2", otherwise it gives the value of "Success3". But all values are printing (Success, Success2 and Success3) at the sametime. I want to print only one value at one time.

Here is my PHP code.

```
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);

$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$product_id = $jfeta['id'];
$jsqla3 = mysql_query("select * from user_star_rate where product_id='$product_id' and      email='$visit_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla3);

if(!is_null($jfeta3)) {
   $ratea = $jfeta3['rate_value'];
   echo "Success = ".$ratea;
   $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
   $arate_num = $jfeta['rate_number'];
} else {
   $arate_num = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   if($jfeta['rate_number'] > 0){ 
       $ratea = $jfeta['rate_score'] / $jfeta['rate_number']; 
       echo "Success2 = ".$ratea;
       $ratea2 = $jfeta['rate_score'];
       $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
       $ratenum = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   }else{ 
       $ratea = $jfeta['rate_score']; 
       echo "Success3 = ".$ratea;
       $ratea2 = $jfeta['rate_score'];
       $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
       $ratenum = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you define "empty" here? If the row does not exist? If a specific column in that row contains... 0? An empty string? `NULL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if($jfeta3)`. It checks whether the statement is null or not. If it is not null or not empty it executes the if part, otherwise it executes the else part.

Answer (score 1):

[`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) is for checking if a value is `null`, not empty. To see if a value is empty use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(!empty($jfeta3)) {
```

It should be noted that `null` values are considered empty and will fail this check. Additional empty values are:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: You should not use `empty` when a simple `if ($jfeta3)` will do exactly the same, without suppressing error reporting in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here: `if (!is_null($jfeta3))`.  `is_null()` checks if a value is null, not empty.  Simply use `if ($jfeta3)`.  If the value is null, the statement will not execute, and if the value is empty, the statement will still not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try using [`mysql_num_rows() > 0`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to replace `!is_null()`.
I've try this code :

```
$product_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);

$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$product_id = $jfeta['id'];
$jsqla3 = mysql_query("select * from user_star_rate where product_id='$product_id' and      email='$visit_email'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla3);

if((mysql_num_rows($jsqla) > 0) && (mysql_num_rows($jsqla3) > 0)) {
   $ratea = $jfeta3['rate_value'];
   echo "Success = ".$ratea;
   $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
   $arate_num = $jfeta['rate_number'];
} else {
   $arate_num = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   if($jfeta['rate_number'] > 0){ 
       $ratea = $jfeta['rate_score'] / $jfeta['rate_number']; 
       echo "Success2 = ".$ratea;
       $ratea2 = $jfeta['rate_score'];
       $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
       $ratenum = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   }else{ 
       $ratea = $jfeta['rate_score']; 
       echo "Success3 = ".$ratea;
       $ratea2 = $jfeta['rate_score'];
       $rateid = $jfeta['id'];
       $ratenum = $jfeta['rate_number'];
   }
}
```